# Table not resizing properly in IE7

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-7

I have a script in the link below which works in IE8 nicely.  However, it seems to go wrong a little in IE7.

In IE7, I end up getting a bottom scroll bar with the text in the 2nd column behind the vertical scrollbar.

The text is supposed to move a little automatically to the left if a scrollbar is added because of the `overflow:auto` in the CSS.

How can I get this to work so it resizes properly without having the text go behind the vertical scrollbar?

Here is a jsfiddle of it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/9vEdw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "easy-but-not-awesome" fix is to replace `width: 100%` with `width: 280px` on `#tblData`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/9vEdw/3/